# Confused by what gsub is doing

Tags: r

Still new to r, and I am confused by what `gsub` is doing. I have data that looks like

[image]

I want to remove the `FROM` in the strings. So, I used `gsub` as:

```
x <- gsub("FROM","",x)
```

I thought that `gsub` would run through all the strings and remove all the `FROM` and return my object. However, it creates a value of x with all the data listed out.

I tried `x <- as.data.frame(x)` to see if it would convert the value into data, but created a data.frame with two obs containing all the strings and numbers.

What do I need to do to remove the strings from my data and keep it as a data.frame?

Comment: Please edit with the results of `dput(x)`, not a picture of your data.

Comment: It depends on the structure of `x`. `gsub` can handle most anything, as long as it's all strings; if you have a `data.frame` with some string columns and some other things, just pass it the column.

Comment: Try `x$Offense <- gsub("FROM","", x$Offense)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're trying to run `gsub()` on the entire data frame. The correct method is to run `gsub()` on the column(s) you want to replace strings in.

For example, if you want to replace strings in the `Offense` column you would run:

```
x$Offense <- gsub('FROM', '', x$Offsense, fixed = TRUE)
```

This will replace all occurrences of `From` in each row of the `Offense` column. Your resulting data frame `x` will no longer have the string `From`  in the `Offense` column.

Comment: In this specific case they should also set `fixed = TRUE`, since they don't need a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Like the other comments, `gsub` works over columns.  However, you could easily run it to every column in a data.frame using `apply.`

```
d <- data.frame(1:5, c("bob", "bober", "ed", "tim","bobby"), c("fred", "ed", "bobby", "bob", "rob"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(d) <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
d
##   X     Y     Z
## 1 1   bob  fred
## 2 2 bober    ed
## 3 3    ed bobby
## 4 4   tim   bob
## 5 5 bobby   rob


data.frame( apply(d, 2, function(x) { gsub("bob", "", x) }) )
##   X   Y    Z
## 1 1     fred
## 2 2  er   ed
## 3 3  ed   by
## 4 4 tim     
## 5 5  by  rob
```

Comment: Don't use `apply` on a data.frame to loop over columns. It will convert column classes, because it turns the data.frame into a matrix. Use `lapply` and loop only over character and factor columns.

Answer (score 0):

`gsub("FROM", "", input)` does as you say. It will loop through the column vector you specify in the `input` argument and replace each instance of `"FROM"` in each string element of the column with `""`. See the example below using a subset of your data. The column `offense2` contains your cleaned data.

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,2,3))
names(df)[1] <- "counts"
df$offense <- c("THEFT - (FROM MOTOR VEHICLE)", "THEFT - (ALL OTHER LARCENY)", "THEFT - (THEFT FROM BUILDING)")
df$offense2 <- gsub("FROM", "", df$offense)

> df
  counts                       offense                    offense2
1      1  THEFT - (FROM MOTOR VEHICLE)    THEFT - ( MOTOR VEHICLE)
2      2   THEFT - (ALL OTHER LARCENY) THEFT - (ALL OTHER LARCENY)
3      3 THEFT - (THEFT FROM BUILDING)   THEFT - (THEFT  BUILDING)
```